# Why do I get an 'Unknown column' error for a mysql query?

Tags: mysql

The following `mysql` query

```
select * from PrivateData.Table1 AS m 
LEFT JOIN 
PrivateData.Table2 AS i 
ON m.GUID = i.OutId;
```

works just fine while this query:

```
delete m,i from PrivateData.Table1 AS m 
LEFT JOIN 
PrivateData.Table2 AS i 
ON m.GUID = i.OutId;
```

gives an error:

**ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected**

Why is that the case? How can i delete the selected rows from the tables otherwise?

P.S.: I am no expert in `mysql` queries.

Comment: Your `delete` query syntax is wrong, it must be: `delete from ...`.

Comment: That error means you have not selected a database... Kinda obvious :) In your connect, you miss a `use DATABASENAME` there.

Comment: @Martijn: There is no `use DATABASENAME` statement in my first query, which returns a list of entries without error.

Comment: @Martijn: No. statements show that the tables are from `PrivateData` database. Explicit call to `use database` is not required. Error is somewhere else.

Comment: Your posting title says `Unknown column` error? If so, `Table1.GUID` or `Table2.OutId` must be wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by 'wrong'? If they are 'wrong', then the first query also should not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether it is well-related to the question but worth a try. From [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html):

> For alias references in the list of tables from which to delete rows
>   in a multiple-table delete, the default database is used unless one is
>   specified explicitly. For example, if the default database is db1, the
>   following statement does not work because the unqualified alias
>   reference a2 is interpreted as having a database of db1:

```
DELETE a1, a2 FROM db1.t1 AS a1 INNER JOIN db2.t2 AS a2
WHERE a1.id=a2.id;
```

> To correctly match an alias that refers to a table outside the
>   default database, you must explicitly qualify the reference with the
>   name of the proper database:

```
DELETE a1, db2.a2 FROM db1.t1 AS a1
INNER JOIN db2.t2 AS a2
WHERE a1.id=a2.id;
```

---

Try to specify explicitly your database:

```
delete PrivateData.m, PrivateData.i from PrivateData.Table1 AS m 
LEFT JOIN 
PrivateData.Table2 AS i 
ON m.GUID = i.OutId;
```

Comment: This looks like a reasonable explanation. And your suggested query works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Little modifications will work

```
delete from m,i using PrivateData.Table1 AS m LEFT JOIN PrivateData.Table2 AS i ON m.GUID = i.OutId;
```

Comment: I get `ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected`

Answer (score 0):

***MySQL ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected:***

***simple one:***

*You need to tell MySQL which database to use:*

```
USE database_name;
```

*before you create a table.*

*In case the database does not exist, you need to create it as:*

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name;
```

*followed by:*

```
USE database_name;
```

***Another one:with brief example***

*While I was trying to view the tables in a given database, I encountered the above error. What happens is that when you connect to a MySQL server, it doesn't choose a database for you unless you explicitly specify it.*

*If you only use,*

```
mysql --userusername --passwordpassword
or
mysql -uusername -ppassword
```

*then the MySQL client just connects to the database server. After this, you will have to specify the database name, which you intend to use:*

```
use database_name
```

*If you don’t like the above method, what you can do is directly specify the database at startup only.*

*The syntax for the same is:*

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword database_name
```

---

```
For ex., mysql –ugaurav –pchhabra testdb
```

[***click to sqlfiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64ffc/1)

[image: look here]

Comment: This does not explain why the first query runs without problem, without selecting a database first.